Can I label ticks in matplotlib imshow() using a custom method?
Let's say I wanted to plot a numpy matrix as an image, so I used matplotlib's imshow() function.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
a = numpy.random.random((16,16))
plt.imshow(a)
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x000001F3EE029DD0>
plt.show()

imshow output for a random matrix.
I have some non-linear function that takes an integer as input and outputs an integer. On the y-axis, I want the labels to be in the same place (that specific place in the Numpy array), but I want them first to be converted by this function. On the y-axis, I'd like to see f(0), f(2) ... f(14) instead of 0,2...14. Is this possible with Matplotlib?
I tried to create a list comprehension;
ticks = [f(x) for x in range(0,16,2)]
and then set the y ticks based on this post:
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.set_yticklabels(ticks)
And ended up with two different figures, neither of which had the labels I wanted.

You can use yticks():
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


f = lambda x: x ** 2
a = np.random.random((16, 16))
plt.imshow(a)
ticks = [f(x) for x in range(0, 16, 2)]
plt.yticks(ticks=range(0, 16, 2), labels=ticks)
plt.show()


Prints

